# Translation management tool?

Tags: json, internationalization, translation, i18next

I'm looking for a tool that can help manage i18n translations with non-technical translating staff. Something where translators can login with credentials, navigate to their respective language, make changes/translate new keys, save, and quit.

Our translations are stored in nested JSON in the typical i18n style:

```
// en.json
{
  "hello":"Hello",
  "world":"World"
}
```

These translations are stored in a git repository and pulled into the main project this way, so hopefully a translation management tool could be given repo access and push/pull as needed?

Comment: http://locize.com might be a good option. Comes from the makers of i18next.

Answer (score 2):

http://locize.com is great. Comes from the makers of **i18next**. Offers a lot of features to keep translations consistent. On top of that it enables you to edit your translations with an Incontext Editor too.

Comment: even if from i18next people it also supports the icu format better than anything else out there. -> just give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at phraseapp.com. They offer exactly what you're looking for. One central cloud based place where all your translator can log-in, translate their respective language and check it in for approval.
Can be easily integrated into your existing workflow via API.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: btw: Phraseapp.com comes with a GutHub integration by default

Comment: Yes, I see the GitHub integration. But that appears to just be pulling, not pushing? How does the data get form PhraseApp to a repository? Also we are using BitBucket, not GitHub so it's rather useless...

Answer (score 0):

PhraseApp is definitely a solution. OneSky, webtranslateit and transifex are similar.
There are open source solutions too:
https://poeditor.com/kb/json-localization
This is a desktop tool, but you could just map your git repsitory and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be [Weblate](https://weblate.org/) - it [supports BitBucket](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/continuous.html#automatically-receiving-changes-from-bitbucket) and [simple JSON files](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#json-files), so it might be good fit for you. It's free software, so you can run your own copy or use [hosting options](https://weblate.org/hosting/) (free for free software).

(I'm author of Weblate)

Comment: Wow, that is a very comprehensive tool - thanks. Does it support nested JSON, or no? Do you still maintain the project actively?

Comment: Yes, the project is still actively developed (latest release was just last week). As for nested JSON, it's not directly supported, but there is workaround to make it possible (see the [docs](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#json-files)).